# How to set server name, login and password to application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

I am doing FTP-client in Spring boot (Java), i want to keep server name, login, password in application.properties to easy switching server.

How  i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the key-value in your Springboot configuration file, just write a configuration class and automatically inject it where you need to use it.

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("auth")
@Component
public class AuthProperties {
    private boolean enable;
    private List<String> anon;
}
```

[Spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7mpo.png)